# Python: doing multiple column aggregation in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate

I have dataframe where I went to do multiple column aggregations in pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'ser_no': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3],
                'CTRY_NM': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'e', 'e', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'd'],
                'lat': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
                'long': [21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30]})

df2 = df.groupby(['ser_no', 'CTRY_NM']).lat.agg({'avg_lat': np.mean})
```

With this code, I get the mean for `lat`. I would also like to find the mean for `long`.

I tried `df2 = df.groupby(['ser_no', 'CTRY_NM']).lat.agg({'avg_lat': np.mean}).long.agg({'avg_long': np.mean})` but this produces

> AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'long'

If I just do `avg_long`, the code works as well.

```
df2 = df.groupby(['ser_no', 'CTRY_NM']).long.agg({'avg_long': np.mean})

In[2]: df2
Out[42]: 
                avg_long
ser_no CTRY_NM          
1      a            21.5
       b            23.0
2      a            26.0
       b            27.0
       e            24.5
3      b            28.5
       d            30.0
```

Is there a way to do this in one step or is this something I have to do separately and join back later?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think more simplier is use [`GroupBy.mean`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.mean.html):

```
print df.groupby(['ser_no', 'CTRY_NM']).mean()
                 lat  long
ser_no CTRY_NM            
1      a         1.5  21.5
       b         3.0  23.0
2      a         6.0  26.0
       b         7.0  27.0
       e         4.5  24.5
3      b         8.5  28.5
       d        10.0  30.0
```

Ir you need define columns for aggregating:

```
print df.groupby(['ser_no', 'CTRY_NM']).agg({'lat' : 'mean', 'long' : 'mean'})
                 lat  long
ser_no CTRY_NM            
1      a         1.5  21.5
       b         3.0  23.0
2      a         6.0  26.0
       b         7.0  27.0
       e         4.5  24.5
3      b         8.5  28.5
       d        10.0  30.0
```

More info in [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#aggregation).

EDIT:

If you need rename column names - remove `multiindex` in `columns`, you can use `list comprehension`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'ser_no': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3],
                'CTRY_NM': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'e', 'e', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'd'],
                'lat': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
                'long': [21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30],
                'date':pd.date_range(pd.to_datetime('2016-02-24'),
                                     pd.to_datetime('2016-02-28'), freq='10H')})

print df               
  CTRY_NM                date  lat  long  ser_no
0       a 2016-02-24 00:00:00    1    21       1
1       a 2016-02-24 10:00:00    2    22       1
2       b 2016-02-24 20:00:00    3    23       1
3       e 2016-02-25 06:00:00    4    24       2
4       e 2016-02-25 16:00:00    5    25       2
5       a 2016-02-26 02:00:00    6    26       2
6       b 2016-02-26 12:00:00    7    27       2
7       b 2016-02-26 22:00:00    8    28       3
8       b 2016-02-27 08:00:00    9    29       3
9       d 2016-02-27 18:00:00   10    30       3              

df2=df.groupby(['ser_no','CTRY_NM']).agg({'lat':'mean','long':'mean','date':[min,max,'count']})
df2.columns = ['_'.join(col) for col in df2.columns]
```

```
print df2
                lat_mean            date_min            date_max  date_count  \
ser_no CTRY_NM                                                                 
1      a             1.5 2016-02-24 00:00:00 2016-02-24 10:00:00           2   
       b             3.0 2016-02-24 20:00:00 2016-02-24 20:00:00           1   
2      a             6.0 2016-02-26 02:00:00 2016-02-26 02:00:00           1   
       b             7.0 2016-02-26 12:00:00 2016-02-26 12:00:00           1   
       e             4.5 2016-02-25 06:00:00 2016-02-25 16:00:00           2   
3      b             8.5 2016-02-26 22:00:00 2016-02-27 08:00:00           2   
       d            10.0 2016-02-27 18:00:00 2016-02-27 18:00:00           1   

                long_mean  
ser_no CTRY_NM             
1      a             21.5  
       b             23.0  
2      a             26.0  
       b             27.0  
       e             24.5  
3      b             28.5  
       d             30.0
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer but this may cause issues since in the real data set I have columns I don't want to mean. I just made a toy problem for here.

Comment: Well if you have more columns, simply exclude them by subsetting the dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the error because you are first selecting the `lat` column of the dataframe and doing operations on that column. Getting the `long` column through that series is not possible, you need the dataframe.

```
df2 = df.groupby(['ser_no', 'CTRY_NM'])["lat", "long"].agg(np.mean)
```

would do the same operation for both columns. If you want the column names changed, you can rename the columns afterwards:

```
df2 = df.groupby(['ser_no', 'CTRY_NM'])["lat", "long"].agg(np.mean).rename(columns = {"lat": "avg_lat", "long": "avg_long"})
```

---

```
In [22]:
df2 = df.groupby(['ser_no', 'CTRY_NM'])["lat", "long"].agg(np.mean).rename(columns = {"lat": "avg_lat", "long": "avg_long"})
df2
Out[22]:
                    avg_lat avg_long
ser_no  CTRY_NM     
1       a           1.5     21.5
        b           3.0     23.0
2       a           6.0     26.0
        b           7.0     27.0
        e           4.5     24.5
3       b           8.5     28.5
        d           10.0    30.0
```

Comment: Can I string together a dataframe agg and series agg? That is, then do a separate agg on a date column all in one?

Comment: If I understood you correctly, yes.  `.agg` accepts a dictionary but it works differently then you tried to use. Each key will be a column and each value is a function that you want to apply to that column. `df.groupby(['ser_no', 'CTRY_NM']).agg({"lat": np.mean, "long": np.mean, "date": np.max})` would take the averages of lat and long but returns the maximum date for each group, for example.

Comment: You understood correctly but what if for date, I wanted `date.agg({
    'start_dt': min,
    'end_dt': max,
    'number_of_dt': 'count'})` would multiple arguments or is it limited to one?

Comment: Would it look like: `df2 = df.groupby(['ser_no', 'CTRY_NM'])["lat", "long"].agg({'lat':np.mean, 'long':np.mean, 'date': {'start_dt': min, 'end_dt': max, 'number_of_dt': 'count'}}).rename(columns = {"lat": "avg_lat", "long": "avg_long"})`?

Comment: You can specify different functions for the same column in a list: `df.groupby(['ser_no', 'CTRY_NM']).agg({"lat": np.mean, "long": np.mean, "date": ['max', 'min', 'count']})` this would take the max, min, and count of the dates for each group. But again, you need to change the column names later as far as I know.